# What makes C# Garbage Collection slow?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I was wondering which of these parameters have the most impact on GS's performance:

- object count
- object size
- object generation

Specifically, which of these determine how long the CPU freezes all threads in order to clean up. I guess I'm hoping that the number of objects only causes significantly more work *during* execution, but does not extend the duration of the freeze. Like collecting trash into a bag may take more time, if there is more trash, but throwing the bag into a dumpster (or whatever) takes just as long, (almost) regardless of how many items are in it.

Is this thought naive?

Comment: If you want to know what makes something slow you need to measure it.

Comment: Microsoft has some really good documentation around the C# garbage collector. It includes detailed descriptions of when and how GC happens and performance considerations for the points you listed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/ If you have a specific example of an issue you're experiencing, you might want to come back with that problem, but this Q as-is isn't really something that can be answered

Comment: @DourHighArch yes, but how would i specifically measure the duration of a freeze?

Comment: @EricMagers thanks for the link - and for not closing the question ;o)

Comment: Unfortunately, this analogy is completely wrong though it’s clear where it’s coming from. The term “garbage collection” leads to wrong thinking. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57853489/2711488) was written for a Java question, but the principles are the same. In short, there is no work associated with garbage, because a computer’s memory does not rot. All the computer needs, is the knowledge that this memory can be used for other purposes.

Comment: The general rules to keep in your head are 1) Gen0 collections cost _very_ little, 2) Gen1 collections cost more, 3) Gen2 collections cost a lot, and 4) Large Object Heap (LOH) collections only occur with Gen2 collections (and they can provoke Gen2 collections).  If you want to dig around and look at things, use _Performance Monitor_ (aka _PerfMon_) with the _.NET Memory Counters_ pointed at your process.  They can tell you a lot about what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no a single answer to this question but there is a general ["The one rule to remember"](https://github.com/Maoni0/mem-doc/blob/master/doc/.NETMemoryPerformanceAnalysis.md#The-one-rule-to-remember) from Maoni Stephens, the lead developer of .NET GC:

*"What survives usually determines how much work GC needs to do; what doesn't survive usually determines how often a GC is triggered."*

The relation between "how much work GC needs to do" and pauses that it introduce (as it seems you are mostly concerned about this aspect) is a different story and heavily depends on the specific GC implementation.

As I feel you are interested in GC internals, I strongly recommend to read the linked document and also watch my [".NET GC Internals"](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpUkQYy-K8Y-wYcDgDXKhfs6OT8fFQtVm) series.